# Is two-Part Mixed Effects Model for Semi-Continuous Data (GLMMadaptive) the correct analyssi for my data?

Tags: mixed-model, glmmadaptive

I have two relatively simple questions on a two-Part Mixed Effects Model for Semi-Continuous Data I am running using  `GLMMadaptive` .
First of all, I would like to check if I am selecting the appropriate analysis.
The design is repeated measure design in which I test the effect of treatment (2 levels; Between subject) over time. My outcome is continuous but 2 out of 3 data points are 0. By using the function `mixed_model`  and a family  `hurdle.lognormal`, I understand I run two models: a linear mixed model to test how strong is the change in outcome as a function of the predictors considering only the data points that non-zero; a logistic mixed model regression to estimate the probability the outcome is non-zero compared to zero as a function of the predictors. Is it correct? Is the correct approach for my data?
Second, the estimates of the logistic mixed model are log odds or odd ratios?
Third, based on what do you change parameter of  `n_phis` ?
Thank you in advance